# Class not registered error VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

**Hello,
I have converted a VB 6 project to VB.NET 2008
One of the forms throws the following error in the design mode.
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)) 
here is the call stack:**

at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(Guid& clsid, Object punkOuter, Int32 context, Guid& iid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateWithoutLicense(Guid clsid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstanceCore(Guid clsid)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateInstance()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.GetOcxCreate()
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.set_Site(ISite value)
at System.ComponentModel.Container.Add(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.Add(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ComponentCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)

**I copied the dlls in the project to system 32 and registered using Regasm.exe using the visual studio command line tool to make sure all the Dlls have been registered.
but the problem still persists.Is there anything else i can try to make this work?
Please advice.**

Comment: Did you use `codebase` parameter when invoking regasm?

Comment: Is your project set to target AnyCPU by chance? Try setting it to target X86 (Project settings -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options) and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @sharptooth How does that really matter?

Comment: Sorry I can't be more help. I ran into a similar issue and changing the target fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very sure about this solution but In the project properties i added the reference path.so that the application knows where to look for the assemblies and it worked!